# Keep selenium out of focus for user

Tags: c#, windows, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium in C#. I am curious if there is a way I can make it so that as a user you can still do what it is you are doing without being interrupted by selenium. For example, if I am typing something and selenium opens a new tab, my mouse focuses on the tab it opened and doesn't allow me to type unless I click on where I am typing again. Would this be something to do in code or in windows settings?

Answer (score 1):

Run browser in headless mode , in this case the browser runs without GUI so there won't be any interruption

All browsers support headless flag now , add headless argument to capabilities while creating the browser instance

Previously headless browsers like phantomjs used to use webkit rendering engine but now chrome has inbuild headless support and uses same rendering enginee blink

so there is no effect of quality

Comment: While I am aware about using headless mode, I can't use headless due to having extensions. I am specifically trying to find a way without using headless. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

You can run in `headless mode.`

Basically in `headless mode` as name sounds, `there's no windows`. You do not even need browser in your system.

**Code:**

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--headless");
chromeOptions.addArguments("window-size=1920,1080");
```

Comment: While I am aware about using headless mode, I can't use headless due to having extensions. I am specifically trying to find a way without using headless. Thank you though.

Comment: You could deploy your scripts in virtual machines for that matter.

Comment: Could I possibly make it headless by doing that?

Comment: Such as make it so the user as the UI on their end but the selenium is on a vm without them seeing it?

Comment: In VM you won't be doing many stuff, or if you could or your company could afford teamcity, then that'd be great !

Comment: Do you have a link to teamcity? Googling it didn't give me an exact website. My main thing I am interested in is going headless with extensions in chrome.

Comment: I really just want my users to have the UI on their end and the chrome be headless so they can't see it while I have the extensions. I did read about in python they have a vm thing for selenium but I could not find something in c#.

Comment: VM's are independent of programming language. This is the general URL `https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/`, they will host vm for you but it is paid.

Comment: How would I go about having it run my selenium program?

Comment: via API or would it be on the customers pc?

Comment: Once you have the subscription, they will give you a UI and credentials, where you can configure your test suite or build to run in CI/CD env.

Comment: hm doesn't quiet sound exactly what I want. Since mine is for customers I just want them to download my UI and then run the program headless with the chrome extensions. I thought about switching to firefox due to being able to do headless with extensions.